# NSAttributeString in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, nsattributedstring, xamarin.mac

I am working with `xamarin.mac`.

Actually As per requirement, I need to display `NSString` as like below can you please help me.

I successfully applied `Font`, `Color` with the help of `NSAttributeString` But Does not find way to apply `link Attribute`

[image: enter image1 description here]

**Reference:** [using-label-as-a-hyperlink](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10480/using-label-as-a-hyperlink)

```
NSMutableAttributedString attrStr = new NSMutableAttributedString("My cool hyperlink");

var range = new NSRange(8, 9); // Range for "hyperlink" word
var url = new NSUrl("http://google.com/");
var font = _myLablel.Font; // _myLablel is an instance of NSClickableURLTextField class

// We have to setup paragraph if we want to keep original alignment and line break node
var paragraph = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
paragraph.LineBreakMode = _myLabel.Cell.LineBreakMode;
paragraph.Alignment = _myLabel.Alignment;

attrStr.BeginEditing();
    attrStr.AddAttribute(NSAttributedString.LinkAttributeName, url, range);
    attrStr.AddAttribute(NSAttributedString.ForegroundColorAttributeName, NSColor.Blue, range);
    attrStr.AddAttribute(NSAttributedString.UnderlineStyleAttributeName, new NSNumber(1), range);
    attrStr.AddAttribute(NSAttributedString.FontAttributeName, font, new NSRange(0, attrStr.Length)); // Set font for entire string
    attrStr.AddAttribute(NSAttributedString.ParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraph, new NSRange(0, attrStr.Length)); // Optional
attrStr.EndEditing();

_myLabel.AttributedStringValue = attrStr;
```

**Question** how to get event for `hyperlink`?

Thanks. :)

Comment: As mentioned in the link, did you used `NSClickableURLTextField`?

Comment: So is `textField:openURL:` delegate method called? I think that your issue may be on `NSClickableURLTextField`.

Comment: can you please tell me? how can I use it in xamarin?

Comment: As defined here: http://www.nightproductions.net/references/dsclickableurltextfield_reference.html you should be able to do `_myLabel.delegate = self;` (or something like that).

Comment: I am not able to find touch event Hyperlink? please help me out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79509/discussion-between-larme-and-yuyutsu).